# Laravel 5.8: Two round passing data between controller and blade

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, controller, laravel-blade

I am getting undefined variable when passing data from controller to blade the second time.

With Laravel 5.8, I have two actions/methods in a MyController. I have to pass data from controller to view. The first action works fine (MyController@action1 -> Blade1) but the second fails (MyController@action2 -> Blade2).

MyController:

```
public function action1()
{
  ...
  $varialbe1 = ... // everything set correctly here and got it in blade1
  return view('blade1', compact('variable1'));
}

public function action2(Request $request)
{
  ...
  $association = $request->input('association');
  return view('blade2', compact('association'));
}
```

Blade 1

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('route2') }}">
@csrf

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="association" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Association') }}</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <select required="required" id="association" class="form-control" name="association">
     <option></option>
     @foreach ($variable1 as $key => $val)
       <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $val->id }}</option> 
    @endforeach
  </select>
 </div>
 </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
       <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
 {{ __('Submit') }}
         </button>
   </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/route2', 'MyController@action2')->name('route2');
```

Blade 2 (Undefined variable: association)

```
{{ $association }}
```

I have tried different ways to get data in MyController and different to pass data to Blade2 (the way that also works fine with the action1), including:

```
$association = Input::get('association'); 

return redirect()->to('/route2')->with('association', $association); // where route2 load the view
```

Comment: try doing a  `dd($request->all())`. What does it dump?

Comment: Thanks @alberto-bottarini What I notice is that, `route2` is not going through `MyController@action2`. Instead, always redirected to `home` after auth. 
Any though? I couldn't find yet what could be the reason.

Comment: What about your ruote files?

Comment: My route seems good as shown in the next aswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got resolved from another forum.
Should add the action method to the list of exception methods in the middleware as follow:

`$this->middleware('guest')->except(['logout', 'action']);`

As controller has the below middleware in the constructor:

`$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');`

If the User is already logged in, which is the case, they will be redirected to the /home and the controller method will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

My route file seems good (MyController in the previous post = LoginController). Here is my route/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 

Route::post('/route2', 'Auth\LoginController@action2')->name('route2');
```